# Flask Unittest - Type Error because of NoneType argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, python-unittest

I tried to test my code using unittest, where a variable is stored somewhere in a file and accessed using os.getenv

settings.py

```
     import os
     TARGET_VAR = os.getenv('TARGET_VAR_VALUE')
```

some apiclass

```
     from settings import TARGET_VAR
     class someApi:
         def __init__(self):
                print(TARGET_VAR) // good if running normally
     ....rest of func
```

test

```
   def test_extreme_devices(self):
      app = Flask(__name__)
      app.config["LOGIN_DISABLED"] = True


      api = flask_restful.Api(app)

      api.add_resource('someApi', '/devices/')

      with app.test_client() as client:
         res = client.get('/devices/')

         self.assertEqual(res.status_code, 200)
```

.env

```
 TARGET_VAR_VALUE='some target value'
```

This is running good but not when running test
I am confused when running test for testing the someApi class, I got the error

```
     TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 
     'NoneType'
```

obviously for the TARGET_VAR is NoneType, even if its value is set in .env

It will work if I add the actual value directly to it

```
   TARGET_VAR = 'actual value'
```

This issue is only on unittest, but not when flask is running and accessing the route(like postman)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could be that when you are running the flask app locally the environment already has `TARGET_VAR_VALUE` loading into the os environment.

If you use something like [python-dotenv](https://github.com/theskumar/python-dotenv) when running your unittests, you can ensure there's a consistent environment. Just by specifying the correct .env file to use and ensuring it overrides any other env vars:

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv("tests/test.env", override=True)
```

`tests/test.env`

```sh
TARGET_VAR_VALUE='some target value'
```

Comment: This is correct answer. Also I can make it work by manually exporting variable `export TEST_VAR1='value' ..etc, but thats a tedious work to do

Comment: I wrote a library to ensure config vars from the env raise when they're not defined, and also supports specifying the .env file: https://github.com/foxyblue/py-envconfig